# Superimpose video if different duration

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have 2 videos. I overlay one video over another with this code:

```
-stream_loop {LoopCount} -i 1.mp4 -c copy -y 2.mp4
-i 2.mp4 -i preresult.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=shortest=1[out]" -map "[out]" -y result.mp4
```

**{LoopCount}** - this is a variable that stores the value of how many times the overlay video is longer than the original video.

Please tell me how to combine these two commands in **filter_complex** so that ffmpeg can loop the overlay video as many times so that it matches the duration of the **preresult.mp4**?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-stream_loop -1 -i 1.mp4 -i preresult.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=shortest=1[out]" -map "[out]" -y result.mp4`

`-1` sets stream_loop to loop indefinitely, making preresult the shorter video in overlay filter.

Comment: Yes I tried this option. but I need the final video to be as long as the preresult.mp4. for example, overlay video lasts 3 seconds, and preresult 15 seconds. the output should be a video with a duration of 15 seconds, and during these 15 seconds overlay video should loop. now the final video will be 3 seconds long, as the parameter is specified shortest=1.

Comment: Upgrade ffmpeg to at least 4.1. stream_loop was buggy till a few months ago.

Comment: Thank you, upgrade to the nightly build helped.